# Loading DB2 table rows as Marklogic documents

Tags: db2, loading, marklogic

Is there any tool to quickly convert a DB2 table rows into collection of XML documents that we can load to Marklogic?

Answer (score 1):

DB2 supports the SQL/XML publishing extensions that were introduced in SQL:2003. These functions include XMLSERIALIZE, XMLELEMENT, XMLATTRIBUTE, and XMLFOREST, and are easily added to a SQL SELECT statement to produce a simple, well-formed XML document for each row in the result set. By writing queries that retrieve the table names and column layouts from DB2's catalog views, it is possible to automate the creation of the XML-publishing SELECT statements for a large number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use the MLSQL toolkit ( http://developer.marklogic.com/code/mlsql ). It allows accessing relational databases from within your XQuery code in MarkLogic. Not sure how the returned data actually looks like, but it should be easy to process it within XQuery, and insert your data as XML into MarkLogic.

Just make sure not to try to load a million records in one statement, but instead try to spawn batches of lets say 1000 records at a time. Spawning will also allow for handling it with multiple threads, so should be faster for that reason too..

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to **stream** from DB2 to MarkLogic?  Or can you temporarily **dump** all the documents to an intermediary filesystem and then read them in?  If you can dump, then simply use some DB2 tooling (like @Fred's answer above) to export the rows to a bunch of XML documenets in a filesystem and use one of many methods for reading in a directory full of XML files into MarkLogic (like Information Studio (UI or apis), RecordLoader, and so on).

If you have don't want to store them in the filesystem as an intermediary, then you could write an InformationStudio plugin for MarkLogic that will pull out each row and insert a document into MarkLogic.  You'd like need some web-service or rest endpoint that the plugin could call to extract the document data from DB2.

Alternatively, I suspect you could use the DB2 tooling (described by @Fred) that will let you execute some code per row of your table.  If you can do that in Java (or .Net), then pull in the MarkLogic XCC APIs which will give you the ability to write documents into MarkLogic.